# converting .wgz to .sis

Tags: symbian, sis

Can I pack my .wgz widget to a .sis file?
Thanks for attention.

Comment: You might wish to ask this on Forum Nokia - http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/

Comment: Why would you want to turn a widget installation file into a Symbian app installation package? What is the problem you are trying to fix?

Comment: As far as I know both are containers of sorts, with sis files just being a renamed zip file if I remember correctly

Answer (score 1):

A .wgz file is just a zip archive, whereas a .sis file is an installation script, so you can't really "convert" a .wgz to a .sis file.

However, you can package your widget in a .sis file together with Nokia's Software Installer package, which will allow your widget to be installed like a "normal" application.

All you need is on [this wiki page of Forum Nokia](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Installing_Java_apps_and_WRT_widgets_using_sis_files)